# How to escape the root prompt (#) in a code block in Markdown

Tags: escaping, markdown, prompt

In a markdown document I'd like my root prompt in a bash's code block doesn't look like a comment line like this :

```sh
root@docker:~# docker images     
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
bash          latest    f72dd207f6f4   2 weeks ago    13.6MB
```

I have tried the usual escaping methods whitch do not work because is code block :

```
\\#
\#
##
&#35;
```

Is there a way to achieve an hash sign for making a root prompt without making a comment line ?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `a8u9r0cmurc4mr0` as the language identifier to disable syntax highlighting. Any other gibberish works.

Comment: That's a nice workaround as long as you don't have real comments in code block. Thanks  
But if there was a solution just for the prompt, it would be better.